# Dropping internet and display frozen

Tags: 11.10, unity

I have a Toshiba satellite with an AMD c-50 processor, 4 gig of ram, AMD Radeon HD 6250 Graphics. Dualboot with Win 7 64-bit, Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

Internet always disconnects(wired connection) after couple of minutes. Downloads and general internet use is slow.

Always a problem with my screen. It suddenly freezes and there is some moving snow(like a tv when there is no signal) with a faint background of the normal screen behind the snow! I'm a normal user, so I don't know how to use the shell to play in Ubuntu.

Win 7 use is perfect, no problems like that.

Is there someone who knows how to fix these problems?

thank you

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.